# Git :- to know current version of a file in local disk

Tags: git

As I understand, git log  can help to know history of all of the commits of a particular file.
However, I don't know the version of file at my local disk. Git status can tell me the MASTER version of the repo but I would like to know the version of my local copy.

Comment: This isn't clear - is your "local copy" in a local clone of the repo?  Or is it just a standalone file?  (In the latter case, Git can't help you, AFAIK.)

Comment: What do you mean by "version" of the file?

Comment: @Oliver, what is use of doing git log and git status on a standalone file. it has to be a local clone.

Comment: @David, how do we differentiate between two committed version of a file ? There has to be a version/tag or commit version attached or something to different commits.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.  My best guess is that you are looking at the case where someone has done `git checkout <revspec> -- <path>` at some earlier point, and left this anachronic version of the file in the work tree.  You now wish to know "what revspec was used to check it out".  But that's just a guess as to what you're asking; you will need to clarify.

Comment: `git log`  on a particular file is giving me a information as commit **ABCDEFGH** . Can I use this commit information **ABCDEFGH** to `git checkout` that particular commit of the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but the closest git has to a "version" of a file is the hash of the file. To determine that, use `git hash-object <filename>`.

**Edit**: based on your comments, I *think* what you are asking is how to get a version of a file from a previous commit. To do that, use `git checkout <commit> path/to/file`.

Comment: Let's say I have a master version of a file A (Called version **X1** for reference and in local area **Y1**). Now, I make changes to file A and `git commit A`. This new commit will now become master version of the file (Called version **X2** for reference and local Area **Y2**). After that also there has been few unknown number of commits happened to this file.

Now, I want to get the version **X1** of file **A** in local area **Y3** after few months down the line. How can I Do that ?

Comment: @sourabh: this doesn't make any sense. What are these different "local areas"?  What do you mean by " get the version X1"?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth. These local areas can be disk where you keep copy of your code. Please let me what you call a disk where you keep copy of your code. I will try to keep up with your nomenclature.

Comment: @David. `git log <path file>` should give me commit number which I can use for  `git checkout <commit> <path file>. Correct ?

Comment: @sourabh - the sarcasm is great, but the fact that remains that nobody here understands your problem explanation.

Comment: @Sourabh - yes, though you are not just limited to those commits. You can use any commit that was performed since the file was added to the repo.

Comment: @DavidDeutsch. Thanks for the answer. Also, if you could help me to rephrase the question so that it is more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

`git describe [--tages]` should be what you want.